# Parsing with nltk of a Recursive Grammar

Tags: parsing, nltk

I must be missing something fundamental about recursively defined nonterminals giving issue, but all I want to do is to recognize something like a regular expression, where a series of numbers followed by a series of letters.

```
from nltk import CFG
import nltk

grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> N L
N -> N | '1' | '2' | '3'
L -> L | 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
""")

from nltk.parse import BottomUpChartParser
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)

sentence = '1 2 1 3 A C B C'.split()

for t in parser.parse(sentence):
    print(t)
```

the above code returns an empty parse and nothing is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar would need to be something like:

```js
from nltk import CFG, ChartParser

grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> N L
N -> N N | '1' | '2' | '3'
L -> L L | 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
""")

parser = ChartParser(grammar)
sentence = '1 2 1 3 A C B C'.split()
for t in parser.parse(sentence):
    print(t)
    break
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pysnippet/pysnippet@latest/snippet.min.js"></script>
```

Using `N -> N N` as an example: the first `N` could be "eaten up" and transformed into a `1` when parsing the sentence, leaving the next `N` to go on and produce another `N -> N N`.

But this will result in a lot of possible parses, for something more efficient you probably want something like this:

```js
from nltk import CFG, ChartParser

grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> N L
N -> '1' N | '2' N | '3' N | '1' | '2' | '3'
L -> 'A' L | 'B' L | 'C' L | 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
""")

parser = ChartParser(grammar)
sentence = '1 2 1 3 A C B C'.split()
for t in parser.parse(sentence):
    print(t)
    break
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pysnippet/pysnippet@latest/snippet.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Regular Version**. The language from the question: "*one or more numbers followed by one or more letters*" or `(1,2,3)+(A,B,C)+` is a regular language, so we can represent it with a [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar):

```js
from nltk import CFG, ChartParser

grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> N
N -> '1' N | '2' N | '3' N | '1' | '2' | '3' | L
L -> 'A' L | 'B' L | 'C' L | 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
""")

parser = ChartParser(grammar)
sentence = '1 2 1 3 A C B C'.split()
for t in parser.parse(sentence):
    print(t)
    break
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pysnippet/pysnippet@latest/snippet.min.js"></script>
```

Try all three out and see what the parses look like on different inputs!

Comment: thank you, this is what I missed. yesterday I was so tired I missed the fact that you had to duplicate the N for the list of numbers to get longer haha, and the additional recommendation you put for making the set of parsers more limited is invaluable. thank you for being so kind